# Android Multiple Apk Support

Tags: android, upload, google-play, apk

I have to upload multiple  .apk files with expansion  for tablet and handset(handset and phablet).

I have used the below code for tablet version's manifest file:

```
 android:versionCode="2"
 android:versionName="3.0" >
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <compatible-screens>
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="213"
            android:screenSize="large" />

        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />

    </compatible-screens>
Code for hand set version app manifest file :
   android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="3.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <compatible-screens>


        <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="xlarge" />

        <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="xlarge" />


        <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="xlarge" />

        <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="xlarge" />
```

But problem is that app is incompatible with Galaxy s4,Htc One and Galaxy S and  all tablet.

If any body have idea about how to make the app. compatible with all tablet and Galaxy s4 ,htc one and Galaxy S device . what code should i put  for manifest file for tablet version and handset version app ?

Thanks 
Nirav Modh

Answer (score 1):

Samsung S4,HTC one,Note 3 takes the following :

```
<screen android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" android:screenSize="xxlarge" />
```